# What does center middle dot in pronunciation transcription might mean

Tags: pronunciation

I know only 2 sources (websited) where I can see how to pronounce Japanese words. These sites are OJAD and WaDoku.

[image]

I like everyting, but in WaDoku transcription they put middle dot, which I do not know what might mean.

Can you please, explain me, how this dot influence pronunciation?
For example, what is the difference in pronuciation with dot [だい･とし] vs w/o dot [だいとし]?

Does this dot mean some kind of little pause?

[だい･とし] = [dai][pause][toshi]
[だいとし] = [daitoshi]

Or maybe WaDoku just put it for "beauty"-reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am fairly certain that the・dot does not indicate a pause, as that fundamentally changes the pronunciation of the words. It clearly is not to do with the pitch accent either as that is shown in the light grey dotted line.

I would venture that the・is an aid to reader on how to parse the word. For example, I checked the word 人間関係 (human relations) on wadoku. This word is a compound of the word 人間 (human) and 関係 (relation, relationship, concern); and it shows にんげん・かんけい as the reading. So, the・I think is just showing where you “break” the word up into smaller words/suffixes/prefixes which meaningfully contribute to the meaning of the word.

In the case of your example 大都市, I think it is showing だい・とし as the 大 is essentially acting as a prefix to 都市 to modify the meaning from “city” to “large city”.

Would that interpretation make sense with other instances that you have seen on that website?

Comment: This is exactly right.

Comment: @henreetee Thank's for explanaition. Anyway, your version is the only one reasonable, I can even imagine. I just wonder If to follow your logic why they divide into [dai * toshi] instead of [dai * to * shi], because in Jananese 都市 [toshi] is a word and 都[to] is a word and 市 [shi] is a word too.

Comment: @Tchibi-kun but you wouldn't have 都 and 市 next to each other like that unless they were making a single word together. 大 is functioning as a prefix, and so it can be thought of separately.